# delete data using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

The objective of the method below is to delete the data from the database using entity framework. I am populating the subscriptions entity by passing two parameters and then calling the atttach and remove method of the context class. Bureau entities is the context class.

```
using (BUREAUEntities bureauEntities = new BUREAUEntities())
{
    var subscription = new SubcriptionRepository().GetSusbcriptionBySubscriptionTypeId(subscriptionTypeId, companyId);
    bureauEntities.Subscriptions.Attach((DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.Subscription)subscription);
    bureauEntities.Subscriptions.Remove(subscription);
    bureauEntities.SaveChanges();
}
```

I am getting the following error message at An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker at line

`bureauEntities.Subscriptions.Attach((DataAccessLayer.DatabaseModel.Subscription)subscription);`

Could somebody tell me where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the error means that you retrieved `subscription` from one instance of your `BUREAUEntities` context, while you're trying to remove it from another instance. The cure is to simply be smart about instantiating your context, and it's easy to fall down on that front when using `using`, since it disposes of the instance as soon as the block exits.

Essentially, make sure all your code that will interact with your context is within the same `using` block. Even better, use a DI (dependency injection) container like Ninject or Unity to create a context scoped to the request. Then you never have to worry about ending up with multiple copies of the same context floating around.

Comment: in my controller , i am having only sections that are using the context used within the Using block. So not sure of which other context object is floating around.

Comment: So the code that I have pasted above is also within the Using block and I am trying to populate that entity and delete it.So cant understand why that should be a problem as the object is alive while i am trying to delete it